# Including Om Next source

Tags: om

I want to put debugging messages into the Om Next source. So I am wanting to include it in my own project which uses the Om Next library.

Mine and Om Next are the two sources. I have put them together (i.e. copied the Om Next namespaces across) into the same Lein project and commented out the Om Next library from the project.clj: `[org.omcljs/om "1.0.0-alpha21"]`

This must be a naive approach, because when trying to run the resultant project I get the error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`, which comes from this line in my source:

```
(def person (om/factory Person {:keyfn :name}))
```

How can I get past this error message? Or more generally - how to work with Om Next so debugging messages can be put in the source?

Another way to achieve this would be to be building my own version of the Om Next source. Not too difficult to put debugging messages into the library and then build and install it. A bit inconvenient though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into the `script` folder.

1. Running the `figwheel.clj` script (e.g. `lein trampoline run -m clojure.main script/figwheel.clj`) will build the Devcards examples. Simply point your browser to `localhost:3449/devcards/index.html` to view them.
2. To run Om Next's tests (in the node REPL), at the moment you'll need to do the following:

   a) run the `repl.clj` script (e.g. `lein trampoline run -m clojure.main script/repl.clj`)

   b) in the REPL:

   i) `(require '[om.next.tests])`

   ii) `(in-ns 'om.next.tests)`

   iii) `(run-tests)`

EDIT: since [this commit](https://github.com/omcljs/om/commit/29b036d955b35538dd78e055fd28e7eff26a27b3) it is now possible to run the tests via `bin/test` at the command line. Not deleting the above information since it is still a valid, alternative way to run the tests.

Comment: Does this comment from dnolen: "for people hacking on Om Next - it’s now possible to run the tests from the command line via bin/test" have relevance here? (useful thing to know regardless)

Comment: thanks for reminding me, edited in accordance. If the answer worked out for you, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I didn't try bin/test because am on Windows. Also 2. gave the error `no such file or directory, open 'C:\dev\om\.cljs_node_repl`, even though Node.js is definitely installed. But anyway the question was answered at 1, and I expect the other problems will resolve themselves when I'm on a Linux machine.